# WPF Slider page navigation using a Kinect

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, kinect

I am looking to create a Kinect application that has some navigation elements.

I will be using the coding 4 fun hover buttons but was also looking for something similar to the Xbox Kinect "hover and slide" navigation bars that are used for side-to-side navigation in the xbox kinect dashboard sections.

Are there any ready-to-go/example controls out there I can modify for my own usage?

Answer (score 1):

The majority of samples that are available for Kinect are featured on the Coding4Fun micro-site. I'm not aware of any extra WPF controls that have this feature. The swipe gesture that you see on the XBox Kinect interface (in combination with the button click-style gesture found in the C4F toolkit) can be found within this "Kinect toolkit" project on CodePlex http://kinecttoolkit.codeplex.com/. Combining these two projects together, with some WPF coding should get you the result you are after.